# Query Azure AD MFA information via Graph

Tags: azure, api, graph, multi-factor-authentication

I'm banging my head against the wall trying to do a graph call from a PS script to check the MFA registration status based on a known UPN.  In Graph explorer this works perfectly, I can substitue the username I want to check and it returned that user:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/credentialUserRegistrationDetails?$filter=userPrincipalName eq 'user@domain.com'
```

In a script I'm trying the below, I have what I believe to be the filter correctly but it is not working.  Any idea what the heck I am doing wrong?  I'm beyond frustrated right now :)

```
$RestSplat = @{
    Uri         = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/credentialUserRegistrationDetails?$filter=userPrincipalName eq ''user@domain.com'''
    Headers     = $Authorization
    Method      = 'GET'
    ContentType = "application/json"
}

$UsersResponse = Invoke-RestMethod @RestSplat
$Users = $UsersResponse.value
$Users
```

Comment: Can you define "not working".  Is it throwing an error?  Is it returning nothing?  Is it returning things you don't want returned?

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell takes "$" as a PowerShell command and thus the API would break in PS.
If you want to run the API, "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/credentialUserRegistrationDetails?$filter=..." , inside PowerShell, then you need to put tilde symbol infront of "$" so that PS understands the "$" inside the API is not meant as PS command.